# How do I set a variable based on specific element from database call?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, resultset

Ok, I'll preface this with the fact that I am new to c# and using WebMatrix.  I'm trying to do a database call as part of page and get information specific to "Category" and then use that data from the database to put information on the page - including for example, setting the page title to be the CategoryTitle from the database.  Below is my sample code and I know I am just not understanding something, but basically I get the data from the database (which includes a bunch of stuff about the category like; id, title, description, etc) into an IEnumerable (which i don't fully understand what that is) and then I just want to reference the CategoryTitle (which is the name of the field in the database and result set.  When I use the code below, I get the following error "Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'CategoryTitle' and no extension method 'CategoryTitle' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I know the "categoryData.CategoryTitle;" part is wrong, but how do I do what I am trying to?  I can get it to work using a foreach loop and doing "foreach(var row in categoryData)" and then saying "row.CategoryData", but i feel like i shouldn't have to do that since its only one record in the result set.

```
@{

    Layout = "~/layouts/_layout.cshtml";

    var categoryID = 1;
    IEnumerable<dynamic> categoryData = null;

    var db = Database.Open("Connection"); 
    categoryData = db.Query("exec sp_get_Category @CategoryID=" + categoryID);

    Page.Title = categoryData.CategoryTitle;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get out only one row, otherwise you are trying to get a property out from a collection. Try

```
Page.Title = categoryData.First().CategoryTitle;
```

It will pull out first result only, but if there are no results you'll get an exception. Alternatively, you can do `FirstOrDefault()` which will return first or null; then you can do a null check.

```
var firstValue = categoryData.FirstOrDefault();
if(firstValue == null)
{
    Page.Title = "Some default title":
}
else
{
    Page.Title = firstValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I used the first solution because even though I included the title in my example, I am actually looking to get several pieces of information and put into variables.  It worked perfectly for me!